# Designing sitemap tree using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have simple sitemap tree and I would like to style it like in example ( http://www.csshook.com/cssexamples/how-to-design-css-sitemap-tree ), problem is that this example requires to use same color for background, but my element sitemap-container has  background image. How can I style sitemap tree like in that example, so that I don't have to use single color background? I don't want to use any JavaScript for this, because it's not required.

```
<div class="sitemap-container">
    <ul>
        <li>Page</li>
        <li>Page</li>
        <li>Page
            <ul>
                <li>Page</li>
                <li>Page</li>
                <li>Page</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how the styling in the example forces you to use any background color? Ensure that your imagery (the images for the "connection lines") has a transparent background and you should be able to do whatever you want with the container element's background. — Or am I misunderstanding you somehow?

Comment: Well I had this line troubling me : ul.tree li:last-child { background: #fff url(lastnode.png) no-repeat; }

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ul.tree li:last-child { background: transparent url(lastnode.png) no-repeat; }
```

instead. Does that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Also note that that particular style requires using images to 'draw' the connecting lines of the tree. You will have to make sure that you recreate those images with transparent backgrounds, so that the tree links in front of the list items also show your background.